# How to use different Spark version (Spark 2.4) on YARN cluster deployed with Spark 2.1?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Hortonworks yarn cluster with Spark 2.1.

However I want to run my application with spark 2.3+ (because an essential third-party ML library in use needs it).

Do we have to use `spark-submit` from the Spark 2.1 version or we have to submit job to yarn using Java or Scala with a FAT jar? Is this even possible? What about Hadoop libraries?

Answer (score 2):

On a Hortonworks cluster, running a custom spark version in yarn client/cluster mode needs following steps:

1. Download Spark prebuilt file with appropriate hadoop version
2. Extract and unpack into a spark folder. eg. /home/centos/spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/
3. Copy jersey-bundle 1.19.1 jar into spark jar folder [Download from here][1]
4. Create a zip file containing all the jars in spark jar folder. Spark-jar.zip
5. Put this spark-jar.zip file in a world accessible hdfs location such as (hdfs dfs -put spark-jars.zip  /user/centos/data/spark/)
6. get hdp version (hdp-select status hadoop-client): eg output. hadoop-client - **3.0.1.0-187**
7. Use the above hdp version in export commands below
8. export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-/usr/hdp/**3.0.1.0-187**/hadoop/conf}
9. export HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-/usr/hdp/**3.0.1.0-187**/hadoop}
10. export SPARK_HOME=/home/centos/spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/
11. Edit the spark-defaults.conf file in spark_home/conf directory, add following entries

> spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=3.0.1.0-187
>
> spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions -Dhdp.version=3.0.1.0-187

12. create java-opts file in spark_home/conf directory, add below entries and use the above mentioned hdp version

> -Dhdp.version=3.0.1.0-187

13. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
14. spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client    --conf spark.yarn.archive=hdfs:///user/centos/data/spark/spark-jars.zip

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) as the build tool in your project. The project itself could use Java or Scala. I also think that the answer in general would be similar if you used gradle or maven, but the plugins would simply be different. The idea is the same.

---

You have to use an assembly plugin (e.g. [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)) that is going to bundle all non-`Provided` dependencies together, including Apache Spark, in order to create a so-called **fat jar** or **uber-jar**.

If the custom Apache Spark version is part of the application jar that version is going to be used whatever `spark-submit` you use for deployment. The trick is to trick the classloader so it loads the jars and classes of your choice not `spark-submit`'s (and hence whatever is used in the cluster).

Comment: Here is the link to pom.xml I used to build fat jar.
https://gist.github.com/ankitK1987/231d5907bd273cbce865d019a91a84ce

Comment: Where's the maven assembly plugin? What's https://gist.github.com/ankitK1987/231d5907bd273cbce865d019a91a84ce#file-pom-xml-L26-L32? You have to remove `provided` from the Spark deps?

Comment: Hi Jacek,
I did correction in pom.xml file and used maven assembly plugin as well. However I am still facing the same issue. Attached find the pom.xml link below:

https://gist.github.com/ankitK1987/2d14165e7d578837b554ae015ef7d5eb

Comment: @user8303581 Please answer your own question with the steps. That'd be very helpful for the community! Thanks.